# HttpPost doesn't work in C#, but works correctly in Android

Tags: c#, android, rest, uwp, httpclient

I'm doing a HttpPost to a rest service to Revoke a license. On Android, the request works perfectly. But when doing the post in c#, I get the response

> "No action was found on the controller that matches the request"

In Android:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
{
        String request = serverUrl + "api/Public/RemoveInstall?DeviceID="+deviceId+"&UserID="+m_userID;
        try {
            if(!isNetworkAvailable())
            {
                return "no_accesToken";
            }
            else
            {
                URL url = new URL(request);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setDoOutput(false);
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                conn.setConnectTimeout(1500);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.connect();

                ...
}
```

The code above works perfectly, but in c# it won't work:

```
public async Task<bool> RevokeLicenseAsync(string userId)
{
        if (!IsInternetConnected())
        {
            errorMsg = "No internet connection";
            return false;
        }

        string deviceId = GetDeviceID();

        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DeviceID", deviceId));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserID", userId));

        //the header arguments "ContentType" and "ContentLength are filled in automatically"
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) 
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(serverUrl);

                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/Public/RemoveInstall",formContent))
                {
```

Comment: The second one has `DeviceID=` in the POST, instead of the GET

Comment: In the android request you post the parameters in the url but in the second one you post it in the body. If the first one works then do the same for the second one.

Comment: Oh ok i'll look into it thanks

Comment: @PrisonMike can you show the controller action. what tech stack is it using?

Comment: I don't have access to it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the android request you post the parameters in the url but in the second one you post it in the body.

If the first one works then try do the same for the second one.

```
var requestUri = string.Format("api/Public/RemoveInstall?DeviceID={0}&UserID={1}", deviceId, userId);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(serverUrl);
    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request)) {
        //...other code
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the short and concrete answer

Comment: When should parameters be put in the body instead of the header? Is this because the parameters would be encrypted with ssl if placed in the body?

Comment: @PrisonMike, That is a very broad topic. I am also sure the answer to that is already on the site. My answer was targeted solely  based on the question originally posted where you were trying to access the service using two different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change like following

```
public async Task<bool> RevokeLicenseAsync([FromBody]string userId),
```

if you doing post request with one type parameter, you have to specify FromBody or FormUri